# Initializing a std::vector with default constructor

Tags: c++, std

I have a class field which is a std::vector. I know how many elements I want this vector to contain: N. How do I initialize the vector with N elements?

Comment: Are you referring to the initial *size* or the initial *capacity*?

Comment: @Emile. Initial size I guess. I don't quite follow. Are you referring to using reserve() to reserve capacity?

Comment: Yes, I am. Let me put it in another way: Do you want your vector to initially have N elements, or do you want your vector to be able to grow to N elements without reallocation?

Comment: @Emile. Initially have N elements, answers below by James and Jerry were exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::vector` has a constructor declared as:

```
vector(size_type N, const T& x = T());
```

You can use it to construct the `std::vector` containing `N` copies of `x`.  The default value for `x` is a value initialized `T` (if `T` is a class type with a default constructor then value initialization is default construction).

It's straightforward to initialize a `std::vector` data member using this constructor:

```
struct S {
    std::vector<int> x;
    S() : x(15) { }
}
```

Comment: You've already alluded to the fact that the N elements are copy-constructed.  I don't think there's a way to create a vector in such a way that the elements are default constructed (which is how I interpret the question title), although in C++0x it can be done post-construction using `emplace_back`.

Comment: @Ben:  Well, one element is default constructed here :-).  In C++0x, the constructor I mention is actually two constructors:  `vector(size_type N)` and `vector(size_type N, const T& x)`.  The first one value initializes the `N` elements and does not call any copy constructors.  The `resize` function has similarly been split into two overloads.

Comment: The parameter is default constructed, but it isn't a vector element at all.  Good to know that in C++0x there's now two implementations instead of a default argument.

Answer (score 8):

```
class myclass {
   std::vector<whatever> elements;
public:
   myclass() : elements(N) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

All the constructors that allow you to specify a size also invoke the element's constructor.  If efficiency is paramount, you can use the `reserve()` member function to reserve the size.  This does not actually create any elements, so it is more efficient.  In most cases, though, supplying the size through the vector constructor is just fine.