# Why do I see unusual behavior when using std::vector with a default constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, stl, vector

### Summary

I have seen a few questions on std::vector recently, and out of curiosity I have been playing around with them a little. I've never really used the STL much, but I knew you could use vector to deal with the allocation of arrays of objects, and I could have sworn there was a way to use the default constructor to allocate the items within when the vector is created. Indeed, this question [Initializing a std::vector with default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294629/initializing-a-stdvector-with-default-constructor) deals with initializing a vector using either a copy constructor and default value vs. just using the default constructor.

However, as I have been doing some experimenting in Visual Studio 2010 with a C++ Console Application project, I have not been getting results consistent with this explanation.  According to one of the comments in the answer to the aforementioned question ([given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294629/initializing-a-stdvector-with-default-constructor/5294641#5294641)), if you use, e.g., `std::vector<FooClass> FooArray = new std::vector<FooClass>(20);` it should use the default constructor, and this was indeed the behavior I expected.

However I wrote some tracing code to track objects as they were created, assuming they would be created with the default constructor, and it appeared that every object was just created and subsequently immediately destroyed. Finally after much searching here, there, and everywhere, I went ahead and implemented a copy constructor that printed out information as well. What I am seeing is that if I initialize a vector of `FooClass` using a default value, with, e.g., `new std::vector<FooClass>(20, FooClass())`, then I get the expected result: a `FooClass()` is instantiated, each of the items in the vector is initialized with the copy constructor as a copy of that object, and then the value used as the default is destroyed.

But, if I do `new std::vector<FooClass>(20)`, instead of using the default constructor, it seems to be doing something that's a little (to me) bizarre. Twenty times, a temporary `FooClass` object is created using the default constructor, an element of the array is constructed via the copy constructor using the temporary, and then the temporary is destroyed.

This really just doesn't make sense to me; but I wonder if perhaps I was just doing something wrong.

### The Code

#### `FooClass.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>

class FooClass
{
public:
    FooClass()
    {
        printf("Foo %i Created!\n", NumFoos);

        myFooNumber = FooClass::NumFoos;
        ++FooClass::NumFoos;
        myIsACopy = false;
    }

    FooClass(const FooClass& Another)
    {
        printf("Foo %i (a copy of Foo %i) Created!\n", FooClass::NumFoos, Another.myFooNumber);

        myFooCopiedFrom = Another.myFooNumber;
        myFooNumber = FooClass::NumFoos;
        ++FooClass::NumFoos;
        myIsACopy = true;
    }

    void PrintMe()
    {
        if (myIsACopy)
            printf("I'm Foo %i (a copy of Foo %i)!\n", myFooNumber, myFooCopiedFrom);
        else
            printf("I'm Foo %i!\n", myFooNumber);
    }

    ~FooClass()
    {
        printf("Foo %i Deleted!\n", myFooNumber);
    }

private:
    int myFooCopiedFrom;
    int myFooNumber;
    bool myIsACopy;

private:
    static int NumFoos;

};
```

#### `FooClass.cpp`

```
#include "FooClass.h"

int FooClass::NumFoos = 0;
```

#### `FooVector.cpp`

```
// FooVector.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#include "FooClass.h"

//#define USE_INITIALIZER

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
#ifdef USE_INITIALIZER
    std::vector<FooClass> myFooArray =
        std::vector<FooClass>(5, FooClass());
#else
    std::vector<FooClass> myFooArray =
        std::vector<FooClass>(5);
#endif

    for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
        myFooArray[i].PrintMe();

    printf("We're done!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output with default initializer

```
    Foo 0 Created!
    Foo 1 (a copy of Foo 0) Created!
    Foo 2 (a copy of Foo 0) Created!
    Foo 3 (a copy of Foo 0) Created!
    Foo 4 (a copy of Foo 0) Created!
    Foo 5 (a copy of Foo 0) Created!
    Foo 0 Deleted!
    I'm Foo 1 (a copy of Foo 0)!
    I'm Foo 2 (a copy of Foo 0)!
    I'm Foo 3 (a copy of Foo 0)!
    I'm Foo 4 (a copy of Foo 0)!
    I'm Foo 5 (a copy of Foo 0)!
    We're done!
```

#### Output with no initializer

```
    Foo 0 Created!
    Foo 1 (a copy of Foo 0) Created!
    Foo 0 Deleted!
    Foo 2 Created!
    Foo 3 (a copy of Foo 2) Created!
    Foo 2 Deleted!
    Foo 4 Created!
    Foo 5 (a copy of Foo 4) Created!
    Foo 4 Deleted!
    Foo 6 Created!
    Foo 7 (a copy of Foo 6) Created!
    Foo 6 Deleted!
    Foo 8 Created!
    Foo 9 (a copy of Foo 8) Created!
    Foo 8 Deleted!
    I'm Foo 1 (a copy of Foo 0)!
    I'm Foo 3 (a copy of Foo 2)!
    I'm Foo 5 (a copy of Foo 4)!
    I'm Foo 7 (a copy of Foo 6)!
    I'm Foo 9 (a copy of Foo 8)!
    We're done!
```

### The Question

So... Am I setting up my class improperly and this is the expected behavior? Is this perhaps a quirk of Microsoft's implementation of the STL?

Or is there some other explanation entirely?

### Final Note

I removed the sgi specs and comments thereon, because, as [James's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136275/using-stdvector-with-a-default-constructor/7136356#7136356) pointed out, the sgi specification is not the actual specification.  See, for instance, the resources for [wikipedia's entry on C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_14882#Language_standard) for links to working drafts of the real specs.  Thanks everyone! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in the Visual C++ 2010 Standard Library implementation.  This was also discussed in [Standard library containers producing a lot of copies on rvalues in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865515/standard-library-containers-producing-a-lot-of-copies-on-rvalues-in-gcc).

The correct behavior depends on the version of the C++ specification your compiler and libraries are designed to.

In C++98/C++03 (what was the "current" C++ specification until last week), both versions of your code would call the same `std::vector` constructor, which is declared as:

```
vector(size_type n, const T& x = T(), const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

The constructor makes `n` copies of `x` into the `vector`.  If you don't explicitly provide a `T` object to be copied, one is constructed implicitly via the default argument.  If you compile your code using Visual C++ 2008, you will find that your code has this behavior regardless whether you declare `USE_INITIALIZER`.  In both cases, you'll get the "Output with default initializer" result that you show.

In C++11 (current as of last week), the behavior is changed.  This constructor has been split into two distinct constructors:

```
vector(size_type n, const T& x, const Allocator& = Allocator()); // (1)
vector(size_type n);                                             // (2)
```

**(1)** is used if you explicitly provide an object to be copied and `n` copies of `x` are made into the `vector`.  **(2)** is used if you do not provide an object to be copied:  `n` objects of type `T` are value initialized / default constructed in the `vector`.  No copies at all are made.

So, with a C++11 implementation, if you declare `USE_INITIALIZER`, you'll get the same behavior as in C++03.  If you do not declare `USE_INITIALIZER`, you should get the following output.

```
Foo 0 Created!
Foo 1 Created!
Foo 2 Created!
Foo 3 Created!
Foo 4 Created!
I'm Foo 0!
I'm Foo 1!
I'm Foo 2!
I'm Foo 3!
I'm Foo 4!
We're done!
```

Visual C++ 2010 does not correctly implement the C++11 `std::vector` constructors and it ends up creating and destroying a bunch of objects that it shouldn't.  This should be fixed in a future version of Visual C++.

Comment: So in `c++0x` has the allocator specification been updated to include a version of `allocator::construct` that calls the default constructor??

Comment: @Darren:  Yes:  it now takes a pointer and an optional sequence of arguments to pass to the constructor.

Comment: I do think it's perhaps an ambiguity in the specification; I'm going to update the question...

Comment: ok, it's up. so given the spec from sgi is it really *wrong* (from a meeting-the-spec perspective, not a dont-make-silly-inefficient-implementations perspective (for which it is clearly wrong :D)) to do the default fill constructor with the multiple create/copy/destroy operations? e.g. do you know of any other documentation that shows it to be so? I couldn't find it. :( Thanks for your help James. :) ♡

Comment: The SGI STL specification is not relevant:  the normative specification is the C++ Language Standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2003 until the 2011/2012 revision is published).  The C++ Language Standard explicitly defines the behavior of the constructor(s) as described in this answer.  At this point in time, the SGI STL documentation is merely a handy reference that is "good enough" for day-to-day usage.

Comment: awesome! :) wish I had paid a little more attention to the Wikipedia references on the STL page. :) appreciate your help. :) ♡

Answer (score 1):

The standard allocator provides a `construct` method that is used (internally by `std::vector`) to construct objects on it's buffer. As far as I understand it there is no default constructor version, only a copy constructor version:

```
// construct a new object at address _ptr, by copying from _obj
allocator::construct(pointer _ptr, const_ref _obj)
```

In the second case, where you have not provided an object to the vector's constructor to copy from, a new temporary must be instantiated each time `construct` is called, something like:

```
// obviously simplified, but to construct the ith object in the vector
allocator::construct(&vector_buffer[i], FooClass());
```

I think the standard allows extra constructors/destructors to be called, so there's nothing *wrong* going on, but you could definitely argue that it's sub-optimal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmm; I've done some more research and I think you're right based on the sgi documentation. I'm going to post an update to the question to see what everyone thinks.

Comment: btw, did you have any particular source for the "no default constructor version" statement or was this just something you had seen in a particular implementation? Thanks for your help! :) ♡

Comment: @shelley: I think James's answer + comments covers everything. I'm pretty sure the allocator specifications for `c++03` include only the copy-ctor approach, but apparently the upcoming `c++0x` model is much more flexible, allowing default ctor, copy-ctor and emplace style construction via varardic parameters...

Comment: k that's what I was thinking too, but I asked my question prior to his final answers and I figured I would leave the comment to see if you had additional enlightenment. :)